# Testing HABTM after_add/after_remove callbacks on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mocking, rspec2, shoulda

I have a `Person` class which HABTM `Preferences` - when a preference is added or removed I need to call a method which notifies a third-party API.

Right now my person class looks like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :preferences, :after_add => :send_communication_preference_update

    def send_communication_preference_update(preference)
        ...
    end

end
```

To test this I have the following spec:

```
describe 'person.preferences #after_add' do
  let(:person)  { FactoryGirl.create(:person) }
  let(:pref)    { [Preference.find_by_preference_name("EmailMarketing")] }

  it 'should trigger callback' do
    person.preferences = pref
    person.should_receive(:send_communication_preference_update).with(pref.first)
  end
end
```

However this does not work.

Even losing `with(pref.first)` results in the same error below.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Failure/Error: person.should_receive(:send_communication_preference_update).with(pref.first)
       (#<Person:0x000000086297a8>).send_communication_preference_update(#<Preference preference_id: 4, preference_name: "EmailMarketing", created_at: "2014-07-08 08:31:23", updated_at: "2014-07-08 08:31:23", active: true, default_value: false>)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
```

Why is this?

Comment: change lines order in your specs: you should place `should_receive` before calling assigning

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer and I will award you the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change lines order in your specs: you should place `should_receive` before calling assigning

```
it 'should trigger callback' do
  person.should_receive(:send_communication_preference_update).with(pref.first)
  person.preferences = pref
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up the should_receive before the method you want to test is called.